# three.js simultaneous castShadow and receiveShadow in a large scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, lighting

I'm looking for a way to make realistic self shadows on buildings but using both 
castShadow and receiveShadow produces artifacts.

Currently I found a way of adding a plane on top of the building (just below the flat roof) which drops shadow on it and on the ground. This is a temp workaround but I'd like something better than that i.e. for scenes with light being low above the ground where more detailed shadows will be needed.

It's a large scene where you can drive around in a car so any suggestions how to solve the problem are welcome.

Comment: `dropshadow` is a 2D concept so what exactly do you mean in the context of buildings and 3D in general?

Comment: @gaitat  My brain experienced a short circuit after all day of overheating it. Now edited: castShadow and receiveShadow instead of castShadow and dropShadow

Comment: usually when there are artifacts you need to play with the `shadowBias` attribute.

Comment: did you progress on your problem?

Comment: @gaitat Too busy with hundreds of other features. For now still using my workaround, and shadows look crappy. Also lighted area is massive and using large shadow map slows everything down

Comment: This is a long existing problem that has not been solved. There are several other similar issues posted here and in github.

Comment: @Hobbes Yeah I'm aware of that and that's why I'm making a new post to get some fresh info if i.e. r72 will fix some of these problems